# Can't be: Error in org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils?

Tags: iso-8859-1, apache-commons-io

Why does these 2 blocks of code result in a different byte-array?

Apache Commons IO 2.4:

```
Charset iso_8859_1 = Charset.availableCharsets().get("ISO-8859-1");
return IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileReader(getResourceFile(filename)), iso_8859_1);
```

JDK:

```
Charset iso_8859_1 = Charset.availableCharsets().get("ISO-8859-1");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(baos, iso_8859_1));
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(getResourceFile(filename)), iso_8859_1));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    writer.write(line);

writer.flush();
return baos.toByteArray();
```

Tell me I'm seeing ghosts ...

Comment: The character 'é' seems to get a different byte-value ...

Comment: IOUtils gives the correct value of 0xE9 - the jdk code gives 2 bytes: 0xC3 0xA9

Comment: So it's either an error in InputStreamReader or OutputStreamWriter - or am I completely missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using FileInputStream, since one can't specify charset with a FileReader.

```
IOUtils.toByteArray(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(getResourceFile(filename)), "ISO-8859-1"), "ISO-8859-1")
```

Comment: Misunderstood the method's javadoc - the charset parameter specifies how the byte-array should represent the characters, not how to read them from the reader ...